# Pyramid decorator chaining

Tags: python, pyramid

In my pyramid application I am trying to implement authorization by decorating the view function.
When I use the `config.scan()` function none of the views are added, however if I explicitly add them using `config.add_view()` everything works fine.

I have two file one which defines all the view functions (views.py)

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.response import Response

from functools import wraps

def authorized(func):    #decorator difnition
    @wraps(func)
    def new_func(request):
        if(request.cookies.get('user')):   # authorization
            return func(request)
        else:
            return Response('not authirised')
    return new_func



@view_config(route_name='hello')           # view function being decorated
@authorized
def privileged_action(request):
    return Response('Hello %(name)s!' % request.matchdict)
```

And another file to create the server (serve.py) which imports views.py

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator

from views import privileged_action

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('hello', '/hello/{name}')
    # config.add_view(privileged_action, route_name='hello')   # This works
    config.scan()                                              # This doesn't work
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

This gives 404 not found error if I access using 'http://localhost:8080/hello/a'
Why does this not work?
Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Does `@view_config(route_name='hello')` work if you don't have the `@authorized` decorator?

Comment: Yes. In the above code remove the line `config.scan()` and uncomment `config.add_view(privileged_action, route_name='hello')` it will work as expected.

Comment: Note that Pyramid has pre-built authentication/permissions framework, and in particular @view_config has `permission` attribute which, when set up correctly, would do exactly what your decorator is doing, only better... Just have a feeling that you're re-inventing the bicycle a bit...

Comment: @Sergey I am using the decorators to perform several other common tasks as well. However I'll look into the built-in authentication/permissions framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code with the decorators looks fine.

The documentation for [`Configurator.scan()`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.scan) states for its first argument:

> The package argument should be a Python package or module object (or a dotted Python name which refers to such a package or module). If package is None, the package of the caller is used.

So make sure you are doing`config.scan(views)`, to get your web app dynamically adding your views.

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to fix the problem. Any idea why `config.scan()` does not work with decorated view function?

Comment: What exactly is not working, and what is? Everything should be working now.

Comment: If you are saying everything works (including when functions are decorated), but only doesn't work if you don't pass an argument into scan, then it's because scan didn't "scan" the correct location until you explicitly tell it to. It only scans the current file., and not your `views` file.

Comment: Then why `config.scan()` adds all the undecorated view functions from `views` and why it does not work only with decorated views?

Comment: Out of curiousity, does it work if you remove the `@authorized` decorator?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out the problem, in my project setup I have views.py and server.py are in the same package. When I run the whole package it works. If run only the serve.py it does not run (as you pointed out).